# How can I write this statement in pinescript?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to write this ThinkOrSwim statement in Pinescript:

```
MACD.Diff()
```

I tried this:

```
MACD = ta.macd(close, 12, 6, 9)

ta.sma(MACD, 9)
```

But I get the below error:

```
Syntax error: Variables of array type are not supported!
```

What's the correct way to get the difference between MACD and its moving average in Pinescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ta.macd` returns a tuple of three MACD series: MACD line, signal line and histogram line.

I believe what you are looking for is the histogram line.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script")
[macdLine, signalLine, histLine] = ta.macd(close, 12, 26, 9)
plot(histLine, color=color.red, style=plot.style_histogram)
```

[image]